# Связные списки в с++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Очень сложно разобраться со связными списками(
Помогите разобраться в этой части кода,пожалуйста:

```
class node
{
public:
    int data;   // data
    node *next;  // pointer
    node(int x)
    {
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    node *head;
    //function to add node at front
    void addAtFront(node *n)
    {
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }
```

И в этой:

```
    node *n1 = new node(1);
    node *n2 = new node(2);
    node *n3 = new node(3);
```

Код полностью:

```
class node
{
public:
    int data;   // data
    node *next;  // pointer
    node(int x)
    {
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    node *head;
    //function to add node at front
    void addAtFront(node *n)
    {
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }
    //function to check whether the list is empty
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if (head == NULL) { return 1; }
        else { return 0; }
    }
    //function to add node at the end
    void addAtEnd(node *n)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            node *n2 = getLastNode();
            n2->next = n;
        }
    }
    //function to get the last node
    node* getLastNode()
    {
        node* ptr = head;
        while (ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        return ptr;
    }
    //function to search a value
    node* search(int k)
    {
        node *ptr = head;
        while (ptr != NULL && ptr->data != k)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        return ptr;
    }
    //function to delete any node
    node* deleteNode(int x)
    {
        node *n = search(x);
        node *ptr = head;
        if (ptr == n)
        {
            ptr->next = n->next;
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            while (ptr->next != n)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next = n->next;
            return n;
        }
    }
    //function to print the list nodes
    void printList()
    {
        node *ptr = head;
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            cout << ptr->data << " -> ";
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    LinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList L;

    node *n1 = new node(1);
    node *n2 = new node(2);
    node *n3 = new node(3);

    L.addAtFront(n1);
    L.addAtFront(n2);
    L.addAtEnd(n3);

    L.printList();

    delete n1;
    delete n2;
    delete n3;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Расписать, как создавать объекты через new и как объявлять классы?

Comment: что происходит в этих классах

Comment: класс node даже как то стыдно расписывать - любая книга по с++ расскажет все - там просто создается класс с двумя переменными класса и конструктор, который умеет инициализировать одну "ноду". Функция addAtFront просто добавляет в начало списка переданную ноду.

Comment: прокомментируйте подробнее функцию добавления,пожалуйста, и зачем мы создаем node* head и передаем аргумент в функцию именно нодовского типа?

Comment: я не посмотрел ваш код полностью, но addAtFront точно написали неправильно

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Не вижу ничего неправильного в `addAtFront`. Все правильно. Дизайн всего списка крив изначально, но в рамках такого дизайна в `addAtFront` все в порядке.

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? В чем заключается ваш конкретный вопрос? Почему в качестве принятого ответа помечен какой-то переписанный код (зачем?), когда вопрос состоял в просьбе разобраться с существующим кодом?

Comment: а что в порядке? Клиент должен знать  про узель, создать узель,  потом добавить его в список, или все таки проще добавить число? И в рамках такого дизайна это неправильно, тем более что удобнее еще и иметь возвращаемое значение bool

Comment: и во вторых это непереписанный код  а втретьих что вас волнует - то что не вы ответили?  Вы так сильно хотите ответить на этот вопрос? Давайте я задам вам подобный вопрос и приму только ваш ответ,  что вам это даст? Вы же и без этого великий эксперт!

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Именно так. Дизайн списка в вопросе специально заточен под то, что управление выделением памяти делает именно клиентский код. Сам список никакую память не выделяет и не освобождает, он только хранит узлы. Вы же рассказываете, что это "неправильно"? Нет, ничего неправильного в этом нет. Это именно ваша реализация грубо "неправильна", ибо она нагло навязвает пользователю выделение памяти динамически через new. Это совершенно мимо кассы. Вся суть реализации в вопросе именно в том, чтобы не навязывать пользователю конкретного способа выделения памяти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class LinkedList
{
    // инкапсулируйте данные // пользователью они не нужны
    struct Node  // для читабельности имя класса начинайте с большой буквы
    {
        int data;  
        Node *next; 

        Node(int x) : data(x), next(0) {} // лучше инициализировать так    
    };
    Node *head;
public:
    LinkedList() : head(0) {}
    // в список добавляется не узель, а значение а после 
    // функция пусть возвращает  bool для того, чтоб в любой момент
    // могли узнать, добавился ли новый узель?...
    bool addAtFront(int i)
    {
        // Создаем новый узел для значения
        // Не забудем проверить, что память удалось выделить
        if( Node* node = new Node(i) ) {
            // Новый узел привязывается к старому головному элементу
            node->next = head;            
            // Новый узел сам становится головным элементом
            return  head = node;
        }
         return false; // не удалось
    }
    // смысль структуры Node хранить int и иметь связь со следующей структурой
};
int main()
{  
    LinkedList list;
    list.addAtFront(1);
    list.addAtFront(2);
    list.addAtFront(3);
    // и т. д.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return head = node;` из `bool addAtFront(int i)`??? Это не ошибка, но в чем смысл такого извращения в  `return`? Зачем лепить совершенно не связанные действия в одну строчку? Зачем тут применять конверсию из указателя в `bool` если и так ясно, что надо `return true`?

Comment: `if( Node* node = new Node(i) )` - что это за бессмыслица? С каких это пор результат `new` надо проверять на null-указатель? `new` в С++ никогда не возвращает null-указатель.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71248/discussion-on-answer-by-ar-hovsepyan----).